# Scroll to a div horizontally not working

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I have the following code. I'm trying to scroll to a div horizontally on click of a button.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#clickme").click(function() {

    jQuery("#parent").animate({
      scrollLeft: jQuery("#child").position().left
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}
#child {
  position: absolute;
  right: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <button id="clickme">
    Click Me
  </button>
  <div id="child">
    child div
  </div>
</div>
```

There are no errors in console. What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"It is the body you should animate because it is the one who have a scrollbar."**

Your code should be right if the scenario is like [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/8vLddgp1/),

(Just change your CSS like this)

```
#parent {
  width: 350px; /* Make it shorter for scroll to work */
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
  overflow: scroll; /* To show scrollbar */
}
#child {
  position: absolute;
  right: -150px; /* Make it negative also to make scroll working */
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

As you can see there, your code would work if it is like that..

---

But now, I will base on your current scenario..

From `jQuery("#parent")`, is should be `jQuery("body")`

**WORKING NOW:**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#clickme").click(function() {

    jQuery('body').animate({
      scrollLeft: jQuery("#child").position().left
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}
#child {
  position: absolute;
  right: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <button id="clickme">
    Click Me
  </button>
  <div id="child">
    child div
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't see any animation on button click.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at below code. For scroll animation go for `jQuery("html,body").animation` and not with the `#parent`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("#clickme").click(function() {

    jQuery("html,body").animate({
      scrollLeft: jQuery("#child").position().left
    }, 500);
  });
});
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}
#child {
  position: absolute;
  right: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">
  <button id="clickme">
    Click Me
  </button>
  <div id="child">
    child div
  </div>
</div>
```